# How to position banner ads over UITabbar?

Tags: swift, ads

I want to use ads in my application. I added a tab bar as shown below. I would like the advertisement to appear right above the tab bar.

To do this I added the `bannerView` as a subview on the view that I created. However, it did not show the banner.

How would you create the structure show below?

```
googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-5378899862041789/8532100959"
        googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
        let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
        googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)
        googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, adBannerView.layer.frame.minY, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)
        //googleBannerView.frame = adBannerView.frame
        adBannerView.addSubview(googleBannerView!)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it OK for admob? Because on many forum says, don't put banner next to any button.

Comment: I did this years ago. I was working for the time being. You can also choose other areas to place your ads. This can be top side as a second option.

Comment: So then your app already serve admob like this (banner above tab) for years already? If it so, it should not a problem for admob then.

Comment: It's never a problem for Google (Admob) if I'm not wrong. I bet they are not interested in how the ad is displayed. Its only an issue if something comes over the add and you still earn. It might be a design issue that might draw attention of Apple (see guidelines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by positioning the ad with CGRectMake().

```
googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, (view.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height) - 49, self.view.bounds.size.width, 49)
```

49 is the height of UITabBar.

Comment: I was having the same issues and can confirm that your calculation works. Thanks!