# Admob allowed position

Tags: admob

I have my app for IOS which has a tab at the bottom and the bottom tab will never hide, it has parallel navigation. Its like when you tap something that navigate to other page, it will remain inside the tab.

I am planning to put the admob banner like image below but I read on forums says that don't put admob banner next to or near buttons.

Are there anyone put admob banner like this? If it going to be banned by admob  I will end up to change the app design.

[image]

- image is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978393/how-to-position-banner-ads-over-uitabbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google says in their guidelines for [Discouraged banner implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en): [...] banner ads should not be placed **immediately next** to interactive elements and app content [...]. Leaving 1dp/1px space is *not immediately next to* anymore IMHO. I have banners at the bottom in every app and found many examples online how to add a banner close to (but not next to) interaction elements.

AdMob native ads for example are always quite close to interaction elements by design:

[image: AdMob native ad]